# RubyGem installation can't find header files

Tags: centos, centos5, ruby, rubygems

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 on CentOS 5.3. I installed it by compiling Ruby 1.9.3 from source, along with libyaml. I'm also using rbenv to manage versions, so I placed the compiled installation in ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286, which is where rbenv keeps versions of Ruby.

Everything's been working great, and I'm now installing Gems.  One gem in particular isn't installing yet, however, which makes me think I may be missing a dependency. It's an internal gem, so not listed on RubyGems, but here's the output of a gem install:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing vmc-helper:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/fs/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for expat.h... no
checking for xmlparse.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I'm a Debian guy, so really not that experienced with Redhat/RPM packages and whatnot, so I'm not sure what dependencies I'm missing on my system to get this Gem to install.

Can anyone help me know what packages I need to install for these missing header files missing above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the missing files:

```
checking for expat.h... no
checking for xmlparse.h... no
```

Now use `yum` to search for the package which provides those files:

```
yum provides */expat.h
```

You'll see multiple packages here. The one you're looking for is the one that contains `/usr/include/expat.h` as that is the standard include directory. So install the indicated package:

```
yum install expat-devel
```

Repeat the process for the other file:

```
yum provides */xmlparse.h
```

Here you will fail and get the error `No matches found`. In this case, you'll need to either read the gem source code or contact its developer to find out what package he/she meant for you to have. It should be listed in the gem's documentation as a system requirement (if the developer bothered to write documentation).

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks!